# Intellij not showing `git diff` and `git diff --staged` changes in the UI

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

With the `latest update of IntelliJ`, I am not able to see the `git diff` from the branch. I am only able to see diff of previous commits.

This has become a nightmare for me now.

Attaching the screenshot of Git diff UI tool of IntelliJ.

[image: Version of IntelliJ]

[image: I have local changes which are not committed yet. But it is not visible.]

[image: git diff output using command line]

Comment: You can go to the Commit tab (on the left side of a screen), click on the modified file, and see the diff between local changes and the latest commit.

Please, let me know if it's what you are looking for.

Comment: @RuslanKuleshov that solved my problem! :)